# Use cases of .NET single Task Wait

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am wondering what is the use of creating "hot" task and waiting for it by blocking thread. Example:

```
Task.Run(() => DoWork()).Wait();
```

Because main thread will be blocked until task is not completed I would just run  DoWork() in the main thread without event putting it in new task.

I saw this example in many places across internet (msdn also) and event found such code in our company projects. I can see it useful only if I want to pass cancellation token to running task.

Comment: `Task` is optimized and can make sufficient use of thread pool and multi processors, it is different from manually created `Thread`(In my opinion)

Comment: @LeiYang While you are correct. Question is why would you create `Task` and `Wait()` for it if calling thread is going to be blocked? Why not simply `DoWork()` on main thread itself?

Comment: Because it might run faster than simply `DoWork()`

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to want the task to run on the threadpool (for instance, not using the current synchronization context or task scheduler), I really see no benefit

Comment: If you can link a site where this actual code is used (especially MSDN), maybe we can try to infer the reason

Comment: As I see it, there is no difference in the flow of the program, only exception handling and that execution being dealt with on another thread, while caller just waits. In inline cases this is exactly the same as just calling the method.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx `If the current task has not started execution, the Wait method attempts to remove the task from the scheduler and execute it inline on the current thread`. I understand that msdn example is just to demonstrate how to wait for task, but some beginner developers see such examples and start wrapping code in task because they think it will run faster, probably this is why I found such code in our project :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you've got some 3rd party API written by somebody else. Let's consider the following:

1. You know there are bugs where sometimes the functions hang.
2. You do not have the option to re-write the API yourself.
3. Not enough time to re-write the API yourself.
4. The API works *good enough*.

If any of the above statements are true then you may have a case where you'd create a task and wait for it to finish.

Let's take the first item for example where there is a bug that causes the API functions to hang... If you start a task and wait for the API function to complete (as follows) you don't run the risk of hanging your entire program based on an API that has issues.

```
ThirdPartyApi api = new ThirdPartyApi();
Task apiFunctionRunning = null;

// start the API's function running on it's own thread
apiFunctionRunning = Task.Run(() =>
{
    api.DoWork();
});

// wait for the API function to complete but also time-out if
// there is some problem where it hangs up (give it maybe 5s)
apiFunctionRunning.Wait(5000);
```

Comment: Yes, in this case .Wait(time) is really usefull